# Indexed function

Tags: r, function

All, I am wondering how to index function f(x)

```
f1<-function(x) x/2+5
f2<-function(x) x/3-10
```

So I can call the function something like

```
f[1](x)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store your related functions in a list, don't rely on magic names.

```
f <- list(
    function(x) x/2+5,
    function(x) x/3-10
)

f[[1]](5)
# [1] 7.5

f[[2]](5)
# [1] -8.333333
```